# Center a moving average on a Pandas timeseries object

Tags: pandas

If I used [`cmov_mean`](http://pytseries.sourceforge.net/generated/scikits.timeseries.lib.moving_funcs.cmov_mean.html#scikits.timeseries.lib.moving_funcs.cmov_mean) in `scikits.timeseries`, what should I use when I "resample" in pandas?

When I "resample" my daily averages to monthly and then plot both, I notice a big time offset. *There is a "convention" setting to "start" or "end" but I don't see a "mid" setting.*

Comment: You can use "loffset" argument to adjust the resampled time labels. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.resample.html

Answer (score 1):

Refer to 'Wouter Overmeire' comment which seems to answer the question.

"You can use "loffset" argument to adjust the resampled time labels. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.resample.html"

(I'm posting here to help cleanup unanswered questions.)